# Como dividir a tela com 2 Formulários abertos dentro de um MDI

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Bom dia a todos.
Estou com uma dúvida a respeito de Formulários.
Na minha aplicação, eu posso abrir 2 `forms` com `grids` onde apresentam informações da fábrica.
Esses `Grids` são atualizados a cada 30 segundos, e são abertos com:

```
StartPosition  --> WindowsDefaultLocation.
WindowState --> Normal
Size --> 1002;551
```

**Dúvida:**
Consigo inicializa-los fazendo com que o form1 abra maximizado, porém no botão restaurar eu consiga redimensionar o `Size` dele para metade da tela do monitor?
E o form2 consiga identificar se existe já um form aberto e  redimensionar o Form2 para a segunda metade da tela com mostra o exemplo abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código que estou trabalhando, porém incompleto, estou testando as possibilidades então não está funcional, apenas com uma noção.
Pensei em usar o evento `SizeChanged` para essa aplicação.

```
    int lx, ly;
    int sw, sh;
    private void frm_Visualizar_Grid_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
        {

            lx = this.Location.X;
            ly = this.Location.Y;
            sh = this.Size.Height;

            this.Size = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Size;
            this.Location = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Location;
        }
        frm_principal f = new frm_principal();
        if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized)
        {                  
            //string cont = Application.OpenForms.Count.ToString();
            string cont = f.MdiChildren.Length.ToString();

            if (Convert.ToInt16(cont) < 2)
            {
                //sw = f.MdiParent.Size.Width;

                this.Size = new Size((sw / 2), sh);
                this.Location = new Point(lx,ly);
            }
            else
            {
                sw = f.MdiParent.Size.Width;
                this.Size = new Size((sw / 2), sh);
                //if (this.Location.IsEmpty)
                f.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;

            }
        }
    }
```

Obrigado a todos.

---

Tentei aplicar a dica que nosso amigo João Martins mencionou na resposta mas não obtive exito.

```
    int lx, ly;
    int sw, sh;
    private void frm_Visualizar_Grid_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
        {

            this.Size = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Size;
            this.Location = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Location;
        }
        if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized)
        {
            //foreach (frm_Visualizar_Grid frm in MdiChildren)
            foreach (Form frm in Application.OpenForms)
            {
                this.LayoutMdi(System.Windows.Forms.MdiLayout.TileVertical);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Experimente evocar o seguinte método:

```
this.LayoutMdi(System.Windows.Forms.MdiLayout.TileVertical);
```

Fará com que todos os `MdiChild` se auto-organizem verticalmente.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda João, tentei  aplicar sua dica mas ainda não obtive exito. editei minha pergunta com mais informações.

Comment: @William o código que coloquei é suposto ser utilizado quando todos os forms estiverem redimensionados. É um método que deve ser evocado uma única vez, com o click de um botão, por exemplo.

Comment: Entendi, porém acho que não se aplica nesse caso pois justamente a intenção é não redimensionar com o mouse ou ter um botão  para isso. Somente redimensionar  o form para metade da tela clicando no restaurar.Você teria algum exemplo dessa aplicação? Vou  fazer um novo projeto e tentar exemplificar esse método.

Comment: Atenção que o método `LayoutMdi` tem de ser aplicado ao `MdiParent`, ou seja, ao `form` que contém os filhos.